# NFS Performance Issue Using NAS

Tags: nfs, network-attached-storage, ghettovcb

I am encountering some performances issue using NFS.

Here my configuration:

- A physical NAS with some internal storage plus an external storage.
- A virtual linux machine called GhettoVCB where I have mounted internal NAS storage and external NAS storage using nfs

when I run  this command from GhettoVCB I get just 6.5MB/s
This command copy a file from NAS internal storage to NAS external storage.

[image]

Is it normal?

How can I improve NFS in order to get at least a 20MB/s?

Comment: What is the networking connectivity? (10, 100, 1000mbps? etc)

Comment: It is 1000 full